# Including VersionNumber with record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a version number column in my table and all of them are set to one. However, sometimes accounts get closed or reopened and sometimes they may even get updated. I would like to assign a version Number for each new version of the account, which is made possible through the AccountCreatedDate. So anytime the account is created or updated it provides us with an AccountCreatedDate. So the oldest AccountCreatedDate should get a version number 1, the next should get number 2 and so on. How can this be done please provide code on how to accomplish this. I have provided code that groups the same accounts together as the same  account will have the same TimeID and I have them in ascending order. How can I give them version numbers? Each record does have its own identity value known as InputRowID

```
    Select * from ods.SchedulePayment
    where TimeID IN(
       Select TimeID
       FROM ods.SchedulePayment
       GROUP BY TimeID
       HAVING COUNT(*) >1
   )ORDER BY TimeID, AccountCreatedDate
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `row_nubmer()`:

```
select sp.*,
       row_number() over (partition by TimeID order by AccountCreatedDate) as version_number
from ods.SchedulePayment sp;
```

If you want to `update` the value, then:

```
with toupdate as (
      select sp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by TimeID order by AccountCreatedDate) as new_version_number
      from ods.SchedulePayment sp
     )
update toupdate
    set version_number = new_version_number
    where version_number <> new_version_number or version_number is null;
```

Comment: how do I update if I have 4 records where it is the same account but newer version of that account. Where all of them are currently set to 1 and I want to update them where they should have different version each time so in this instance I should have 4 different versions.

Comment: By new date you can identify

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja this is not working what he had done for the update can you provide a script that does this when all of them are set to 1 right now and I want it to give a new version based off the versionnumber in the previous row?

Answer (score 0):

Row_number() is what you should opt for

```
  Select *, row_number() over (partition 
    by 
 Account order by accountcreationdate 
 asc) from ods.SchedulePayment
     where TimeID IN(
   Select TimeID
   FROM ods.SchedulePayment
   GROUP BY TimeID
   HAVING COUNT(*) >1
    )ORDER BY TimeID, 
   AccountCreatedDate
```